# Exception running example.js puppeteer test

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Trying to follow https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started to install and run my first puppeteer test

I was able to successfully install node and puppeteer. But when trying to run example.js

```js
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I get the following exception

```js
yerr$ node example.js
/Documents/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:712
        catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Documents/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Target.js:19:19)
```

Any inputs here are much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using too old Node.js. The error is caused by [optional catch binding](https://2ality.com/2017/08/optional-catch-binding.html) in the puppeteer code. It is supported [since Node.js 10.3.0](https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding). Try to update the Node.js version. The last puppeteer versions need [Node.js 10.18.1 at least](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage).

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Along with this I had to upgrade the chromium version as well. Thanks